# compare same columns data values based on different date from same table

Tags: oracle

I want to write a query in **oracle** that will give me the last three months of sales record. Query is

```
select  city,CY_date,sum(sales) as cy_sales from table1 where date>trunc(sysdate-90,'DAY') group by city,date.
```

[image]

consider today is 19/04/2022 and Tuesday then this will give me the data from 17/01/2022 (This is taking the last 90 days of data and including all the days in the first week)

I want to add the sales value for these cities for a similar time last year(as shown in py_date and pay_sales). Table1 has the data for the last 10 years. Similar time last year means to compare this year Monday to last year same period Monday. So the data 18/04/2022 will be compared against 19/04/2021(it will be sysdate-364, let me know if there is a better way as this is going to fail in the leap year).

The ***main question*** here is how can I add ***last two columns in same table*** as displayed on shown screen with efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an analytic function with a `RANGE` window to find the previous year's data:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT city,
         dt AS cy_date,
         sales AS cy_sales,
         ADD_MONTHS(dt, -12) AS py_date,
         SUM(sales) OVER (
           PARTITION BY city
           ORDER BY dt
           RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' YEAR PRECEDING
                     AND INTERVAL '1' YEAR PRECEDING
         ) AS py_sales
  FROM   (
    SELECT city,
           TRUNC(dt) AS dt,
           SUM(sales) AS sales
    FROM   table_name
    WHERE  (   dt <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1
           AND dt >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 90)
    OR     (   dt <  TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12)) + 1
           AND dt >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12)) - 90)
    GROUP BY city, TRUNC(dt)
  )
)
WHERE  cy_date <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1
AND    cy_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 90
```

*Note: unlike adding an `INTERVAL` to a date, using an `INTERVAL` in a range window will work correctly around leap years.*

Which, for a minimal example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (city, dt, sales) AS
SELECT 'City' || LEVEL, TRUNC(SYSDATE) - LEVEL +1, 100 * LEVEL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6
UNION ALL
SELECT 'City' || LEVEL, ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - LEVEL +1, -12), 10 * LEVEL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5
```

Outputs:

> | CITY | CY_DATE | CY_SALES | PY_DT | PY_SALES |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | City1 | 19-APR-22 | 100 | 19-APR-21 | 10 |
> | City2 | 18-APR-22 | 200 | 18-APR-21 | 20 |
> | City3 | 17-APR-22 | 300 | 17-APR-21 | 30 |
> | City4 | 16-APR-22 | 400 | 16-APR-21 | 40 |
> | City5 | 15-APR-22 | 500 | 15-APR-21 | 50 |
> | City6 | 14-APR-22 | 600 | 14-APR-21 | *null* |

---

Or, you can generate the totals in a sub-query factoring clause and then join the current year to the previous year using the `ADD_MONTHS` function:

```sql
WITH totals (city, dt, sales) AS (
  SELECT city,
         TRUNC(dt),
         SUM(sales)
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  (   dt <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1
         AND dt >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 90)
  OR     (   dt <  TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12)) + 1
         AND dt >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12)) - 90)
  GROUP BY city, TRUNC(dt)
)
SELECT ct.city,
       ct.dt    AS cy_date,
       ct.sales AS cy_sales,
       pt.dt    AS py_dt,
       pt.sales AS py_sales
FROM   totals ct
       LEFT OUTER JOIN totals pt
       ON (    ct.city = pt.city
           AND ADD_MONTHS(ct.dt, -12) = pt.dt)
WHERE  ct.dt >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 90
```

Which, for the same sample data, outputs:

> | CITY | CY_DATE | CY_SALES | PY_DT | PY_SALES |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | City1 | 19-APR-22 | 100 | 19-APR-21 | 10 |
> | City2 | 18-APR-22 | 200 | 18-APR-21 | 20 |
> | City3 | 17-APR-22 | 300 | 17-APR-21 | 30 |
> | City4 | 16-APR-22 | 400 | 16-APR-21 | 40 |
> | City5 | 15-APR-22 | 500 | 15-APR-21 | 50 |
> | City6 | 14-APR-22 | 600 | *null* | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=91e54ab9a13a0e18699a4119d1404ddf)*

Comment: This is working, but there is a little tricky thing. I am not comparing 18/04/2022 to 18/04/2021 but 19/04/2021. comparing with exact one year ago is fine. The logic why I am comparing 18/04/2022 to 19/04/2022 is that both the day is monday. I am comparing monday this year  to monday last year at same time.how to work on that